# httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True) TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering' using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, httplib

I try to find an element on Amazon

```
def find_amazon_element():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=os.path.join('geckodriver'))
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.get(url='https://www.amazon.com')
    input_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="twotabsearchtextbox"]')
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/div/input')
    input_field.send_keys('vase')
    search_button.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_amazon_element()
```

but I get this error

```
httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True) TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'
```

Comment: It would be better to specify **on which line exactly** you got that exception. Also note that `os.path.join('geckodriver')` returns just `'geckodriver'`, so using `os.path.join` in this case is little confusing...

Comment: Everything is fine except driver path..

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dinakindr/lessons_virt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 377, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'' this is a full error @Andersson

Comment: It is in my project directory /Project/geckodriver, so what a path suppose to be? @AshfaqueMarfani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True) TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'
```

...implies that the **`getresponse()`** method got an unexpected keyword argument **buffering**.

As per the discussion [unexpected keyword argument 'buffering' - python client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326616/unexpected-keyword-argument-buffering-python-client) this exception isn't the source of the exception that stopped your *test execution* but it was in fact being handled when a different exception occurred.

Perhaps the complete *Traceback* would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way.

However, I am sure, if you go down through the *Traceback* you will find a line as, *...During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:...* with an error:

```
Caused by <class 'ConnectionResetError'>:
    [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
```

As per the discussion [urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799251/urllib3-exceptions-protocolerror-connection-aborted-error10054-an-exist) this error is raised due to the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

### Solution

Ensure that the version of the binaries you are using are **compatible** as per the figure below:

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver]